# How do I make this JavaScript work on my local machine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

The code I have below works if it's on my server but when viewed on my local machine it gives me the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

$(document).ready(function() {

default.html (line 24)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(document).ready(function() {

default.html (line 12)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

$(document).ready(function() {
```

CODE:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/site/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slider/src/unslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var unslider = $('.container').unslider();

    $('.arrow').click(function() {
        var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];

        //  Either do unslider.data('unslider').next() or .prev() depending on the className
        unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
    });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.line1').fadeIn(7000);
        $('#slide2').delay(1000).fadeIn(3200);
        $('#slide3').delay(1800).fadeIn(3200);
        $('.line4').delay(4000).fadeIn(3500);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: set up a server. Do not work of file protocol.

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script tag is probably giving your browser trouble. Replace `"//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"` with `"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"` and it should then work.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Your code couldn't find jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Add `http` to

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

`//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js` this is pointing to find jQuery in the local server but the script is not available in the local server so chnage this to `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"`

Answer (score 0):

You could have also downloaded the latest version and placed it in a `js` folder under your docroot. Then you could have accessed it with:

```
<script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```